Show that convergence rate is at least $p+1$
So this is my first time working with convergence rates and i am stuck at this problem.
Let $p$ be constant and $x^* \in (a,b)$ be a fixpoint of the $p+1$-times continous-differentiable function $\phi : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
$\phi'(x^*)=\phi''(x^*)= \dots = \phi^{(p)}(x^*)=0$
Also:
$|\phi^{(p+1)}(x)| \leq M(p+1)!$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$.
Now I want to show that the convergence rate of the fixpoint-iteration
$x_{k+1} := \phi(x_k), k=0,1, \dots$
is convergent with rate (at least) $p+1$ under the given conditions.
I tried a bunch but don't really understand what to do.
I know that i have to show that
$\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{||x^k-x^*||}{||x^{k-1}-x^*||} \in \mathbb{R}$.
Any help on how to proceed?
$\textbf{Edit:}$
I might just found out a way on how to prove this.
Let's use the Taylor-Expansion of $\phi$ in $x^*$:
$\phi(x^k)=\phi(x^*)+\frac{\phi^{(p+1)}(x^*)}{(p+1)!}(x^k-x^*)$.
Therefore we get:
$\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|x^{k+1}-x^*|}{|x^{k}-x^*|}=\limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|\phi(x^k)-\phi(x^*)|}{|x^{k}-x^*|} = \limsup\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|\phi^{(p+1)}(x^*)|}{|(p+1)!|}$
which is $\in \mathbb{R}$.
Would this work?

You need to correct your Taylor formula, the power corresponds to the derivative order. $\phi^k(x)$ is usually the iterative evaluation, the k-fold composition, while $\phi^{(k)}$ denotes the derivative.

@LutzLehmann Thanks, i just fixed it

The Taylor terms are still wrong.
